# Hadoop Mini Cluster Mock (MiniDFSCluster)

Tags: hadoop, testing, mocking, sbt, hdfs

I need your help about **hadoop-minicluster**

I'm working with scala (with sbt) and I try to Mock calls of HDFS. I sow hadoop-minicluster for deploying a little cluster and test on it.

However, when I add the sbt dependency :

**libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-minicluster" % "3.1.0" % Test**

The sources are not added and I can't import the package **org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster**

Do you know how I can solve the problem ?

Thank you for yours answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, it's not in hadoop-minicluster.
Try
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % HADOOP_VERSION classifier "tests"

You also may have to exclude some components, such as
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % HADOOP_VERSION classifier "tests" exclude ("javax.servlet", "servlet-api")

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! `libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.2.0" % Test classifier "tests"`

Comment: I tried like this with hadoop 2.8.5 and I couldn't get the sources.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answer.

So to get the tests files and the sources files (for example with DistributedFileSystem), I use this line in my sbt file :

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "3.1.0" % Test classifier "tests"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.1.0" % Test classifier "tests"

Hadoop-common was needed to compile.

However, I have an other problem when I run my tests :

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
```

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

I sow that it's about HADOOP_HOME in the path, but I did it, but nothing happens..

Comment: I had similar issue and adding `HADOOP_HOME/bin` to the `PATH` variable solved the issue.